# Unable to refresh data in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have one method deactivateUser to deactivate the org users and i want to refresh the data after this method is being called. i tried various examples given to refresh the data but nothing worked.

```
deactivateUser(currentRow){
    this.curntId = currentRow.Id;
    console.log('curntID'+this.curntId);
    deactivateUser({userId:this.curntId})
    .then(result => { this.messageFromImperative = currentRow.Id;
        console.log('this.messageFromImperative'+this.messageFromImperative);
        this.successToast();
        this.refreshData();
    })
    .catch(error => { this.errorFromImperative = error  
        console.log('this.errorFromImperative'+JSON.stringify(this.errorFromImperative));
        console.log('this.errorFromImperative.body.message'+JSON.stringify(this.errorFromImperative.body.message));
        console.log('without stringify'+this.errorFromImperative.body.message);
        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error!!',
            message: this.errorFromImperative.body.message,
            variant: 'Error'
        }),
        );    
        this.refreshData();
})}
```

Comment: Check out the [refreshApex()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/apex) method usage toward the bottom of the doc.  Importing `refreshApex` and using it on an existing variable should help for your LWC

Answer (score 0):

Is the method working? Is the method making the changes to any particular field? 
If it does try this one on LWC (with imperative apex) to refresh the view which probably will help you to see the most recent value in any particular field:

```
    eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire()");
```

Just add it to your successful part of the statement before:

```
this.successToast();
```

Comment: No refreshview is not working

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to refresh the data of a lightning datatable? Could you give more info about the context of what do you mean with refreshing data?

Comment: Yes..I have two tabs onclick of active tab. i am showing the datatable with activeusers and on the click of another tab i am showing deactivated users datatable.

Comment: Okay in this case, i suposs you are moving the activated and deactivated users using .push() and .pop() on the data arrays.

This means it wont refresh, to refresh it, you can use something like this:

let auxArray = this.dataArray;
auxArray.pop(deactivatedUser);
this.dataArray = auxArray;

This way you will make the @track property work and refresh the datatable using data={dataArray}

Comment: Yeah u are right..i am using the same approach

Comment: and is it still not refreshing the data?

Comment: I will implement what u have suggested and then i'll let u know